# Passing function to sails.js with additional data

Tags: javascript, sails.js

I would like to check if a user already exist in the database. If it isn't, I would like to add it. I'm using sails.js v0.10.0-rc7.

```
Item.findOne(id).then(function(obj){
    how can I access id??? so that if obj is empty I can create it?
 }, function(error){
     sails.log.warn("error:"+error);
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the findorCreate-function like this:

```
Item.findOrCreate(id,{id: '213',name:'foouser'}).exec(function(err,resitem){
  if(err){
    sails.log.warn("error:"+error);
  }else{
    sails.log(resitem);
  }
});
```

See: http://beta.sailsjs.org/#/documentation/reference/Models/Model-Methods/findOrCreate.html